# External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, hdmi, external-monitor

After an abnormal shutdown my Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon fails to pick up an external monitor connected via HDMI (xrandr outputs "HDMI-1 disconnected). I am running Ubuntu 20.04; lshw -c video gives the following output:

*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: UHD Graphics 620
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 2
bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
logical name: /dev/fb0
version: 07
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=2560x1440 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1440
resources: iomemory:2f0-2ef iomemory:2f0-2ef irq:137 memory:2ffa000000-2ffaffffff memory:2fa0000000-2fafffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

I am aware that there are many similar questions to this online and have tried various suggestions including:

- rebooting with the monitor connected/disconnected
- looking for additional graphics drivers
- switching display managers (gdm3/lightdm)
- running Ubuntu in Wayland
- disabling secure boot
- deleting xorg configuration files
- running "xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of eDP1^C" (which has output "warning: output HDMI1 not found; ignoring")
- ...
  and of course multiple reboots between attempts.

I am an inexperienced Linux user and don't know what to try next; I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue on one of my laptops with Ubuntu 20.04 (Gigabyte Aero). On the other (Acer ) it connects properly. With respect to `xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of eDP1^C` just substitute `HDMI1` with `HDMI-1`, like so: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --right-of eDP1^C`. This has not solved my issue, though.